Graviton metric interaction
In most discussions on quantum-gravity, graviton is considered as a perturbation that is being added linearly to a flat metric (the $h_{\mu\nu}$ term in $g_{\mu\nu} = \eta_{\mu\nu} + h_{\mu\nu}$). Would it be conceivable to consider cases where graviton actually couples to the metric, like $h_{\mu\nu}g^{\mu\nu}$? In other words, the relation between the graviton and the metric being other than what is considered in linear cases?

Are you assuming that $g$ and $h$ are independent quantities?

Yes. That is the assumption.

Usually they are taken to be not independent.

Yes, I know. So, my question is: do they have to be dependent based on some physics principles,...? Or, would it be conceivable that they "could" be independent?
